# How to pass id from .html to .ts in angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

Basically how the title states, how can I pass an id of an item so when accessing the page I only have that item shown, currently I'm at this stage where I'm stuck in getting the id..

In the .html:

```
<button routerLink='/items/{{item.id}}'>List item</button>
```

In the component:

```
itemArray: GetItems[] = [];    

constructor(){
    item: GetItems[] => {
      this.itemArray.find(item => item.id === id);
    }
}
```

Update 1: //Error AnonymousSubject

```
id: Observable<string>;

constructor(route: ActivatedRoute){
  this.id = route.params.pipe(pluck('id'));
  console.log(this.id);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to get the id like this :

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/items', item.id]">{{ item.id }}</a>
```

```js
id$: Observable<string>; // This is an observable

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.id$ = this.route.params.pipe(pluck('id');
  this.id$.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Another method :

```js
id: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```

Visit [Activated Route](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) and [Activated Route in action](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action).

Comment: Both of them didn't work for me, the first one is stating: Anonymous function, the second one is stating route is not declared...

Comment: Could you update your post and show how did you implements what I told you ?

Comment: I edited my post. The first solution use Observables. You have to subscribe to it to be able to see it's value.

Comment: If you're not used to use Observable, don't hesitate to read [RxJS](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)